# CSS: height of div containing divs

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple div, containing some left floating divs:

```
<div id="group1" style="padding: 10px">
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
</div>
```

Now I have some problems concerning the height of group1. Basically the padding-bottom does not work, as the height of group1 is not dynamic. In the dev tools it shows thats always 21px. depending on the size of the browser window the inner divs need more space. I tried some combinations of height: auto and min-height, but nothing worked.

Do I really have to calculate the height depending on browser window size? There should be something more convenient!

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When child divs are floated, parent divs lose auto-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010227/when-child-divs-are-floated-parent-divs-lose-auto-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div id="group1" style="padding: 10px; width:100%; float:left;">
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that did it. I will never understand css, but I sure love stackoverflow and this community! thanks for help. Will mark that answer as solution asap.

Comment: Maybe you could just add a few words why it works, what you've added, ....

Comment: @Michael You can read about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context it will help you to deal with float and understand why and what's going on :)

Comment: @Michael Also, mind that using float, takes the floatting effect up a level, i do recommend you to read about block formating context which let you decide the way to deal with float among your global layout :)

Answer (score 2):

When a element is using property `float` It doesn't affect the size of parent, it just floats there, even inline element do affect the parent.

So whenever you use such divs it's necessary to clear the floating context.

There are several ways to achieve that:

- Use div with `clear: both;` after floating element within parent
- Add `overflow: hidden;` to parent element
- Add `float` itself to parent, but this might create problem in height of higher level elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
<div id="group1" style="padding: 10px; width:100%; display:table;">
  <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
  <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
  <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
  <div style="width: 180px; float: left">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: would be nice to have some explanation about the display effect :) like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code accordingly and added some required attributes please refer following snippet.

```html
 <div id="group1" style="padding: 10px; border:1px solid; overflow:hidden;">
       <div style="width: 180px; border:1px solid; float: left;">...</div>
       <div style="width: 180px; border:1px solid; float: left;">...</div>
       <div style="width: 180px; border:1px solid; float: left;">...</div>
       <div style="width: 180px; border:1px solid; float: left;">...</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no mandatory semicolon that OP missed. You've just added some optional ones.

Comment: @Sirko I just suggested that placing semicolon after each attribute is a good practice. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is floating inner elements.
One solution is what @LokeshGupta posted. 
But another, if you dont want float parent, is to use clear block:

```
<div id="group1" style="padding: 10px">
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
    <div style="width: 180px; float: left">...</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```